# Naze32 flight controller not connecting to RC

Tags: quadcopter, flight-controller

Cleanflight reads my Naze32, but the RC values aren't responding at all. Everything is connected and double checked that the wires were connected properly and firmware was flashed. Just not getting any feedback from cleanflight for throttle/pitch/yaw.

Comment: This question might be better for the [RCGroups](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/index.php) forum. 

Two things to check off the top of my head (1) the rx / tx are [bound](https://www.propwashed.com/how-to-bind-taranis/), (2) Cleanflight is expecting the right protocol. See [Oscar Liang's blog](https://oscarliang.com/pwm-ppm-sbus-dsm2-dsmx-sumd-difference/) for a good overview of the different rx/tx protocols involved.

Comment: Are you sure that you've properly bound the receiver to the transmitter? An unbound TX RX would lead to no response.